# How to test and compare multiple versions of R functions for a package?

Tags: r, integration-testing

I use unit tests via `testthat` for many of my simpler functions in R but where I have more complex functions combining simple functions and business logic.  I'd like to test the cumulative impact via a before and after view for a sample of inputs. Ideally, I'd like to do this for a variety of candidate changes.

At the moment I'm:

1. Using Rmarkdown documents
2. Loading the package as-is
3. Getting my sample
4. Running my sample through the package as-is and outputting table of results
5. `source`ing new copies of functions
6. Running my sample again and outputting table of results
7. Reloading package and `source`ing different copies of functions as required

This has proven difficult due to some functions that sit in the package namespace still running the package versions of functions, making results unreliable unless I thoroughly reload all downstream dependencies of functions. Additionally, the mechanism is complex to manage and difficult to reuse.

Is there a better strategy for testing candidate changes in R packages?

Answer (score 1):

I've reduced this issue by creating a sub-package in my impact analysis folder that contains the amended functions.

I then use `devtools::load_all` to load these new function versions up.

I can then compare and contrast results by accessing the originals via the namespace e.g. `myoriginalpackage:::testfunction` whilst looking at the new ones with `testfunction`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can replace steps 5 and 7 with "Rcmd build YourPackage" on each version. Then with

```
install.packages("Path/To/MyPackage_1.1.tar.gz", type="source")
```

test the old version, and then replace 1.1 with 1.2

Comment: Hmm but wouldn't that require overwriting files in the R folder repeatedly?

Comment: Yes, as does using source to load the new functions.
I have my package in my dropbox folder, so everytime I hit CTRL+S, Dropbox stores a new copy of the file and I can retreive every version of the last two weeks. Maybe that works for you as well?